# Whats right way to create object (in database) from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do that:

1. User upload file in first controller,
2. In some conditions I show page to user for choose element from file and pass file data to another controller in params: data#new

In data#new:

```
@elm_file = Rails.cache.read(params[:cache_id])
@elm_id = params[:index]
@user_name = params[:name]

new_elm_id = Elm.create_from_file @elm_file, @elm_id, @user_name

if new_elm_id != 0
  redirect_to :action => '', :id => new_elm_id
end

return
```

in Model:

```
new_elm = Elm.new

return new_elm.id
```

The problem is - nothing returned. How can I record new element to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `new` action of the controller `data` returns nothing, because you haven't defined anything behind the `return` argument.

The two other lines, which are supposed to be from your model, returns nothing, because the `id` field is only set for persisted records. You maybe want to persist it with [`create()`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read about difference between new() and create() and understand my mistake in model.